Seaborn lineplot showing year 1970 on x-axis
I want to create a Seaborn lineplot with below (shortened) dataframe as underlying data (Date on x axis and A and B on y axis)



Date
A
B




2024-08-01
48.06
30.9


2024-08-02
49.06
31.9


2024-08-05
50.06
32.9



When I create the lineplot I am getting wrong days though on the x axis (starting from 1970-01-01 and ending at 1970-01-03.
What magic trick is needed here to show the correct dates?
Many thanks as always
plot = sns.lineplot(data = df)

format_ymd = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
plot.xaxis.set_major_formatter(format_ymd)

plt.xticks(rotation=45)


hi if your question was answered please can you mark as correct thanks

Have you checked the 'Date' column you are interested in is in fact a date object? By default, Seaborn and Matplotlib may not interpret the 'Date' column correctly. However you can check this.
I have made some changes this should be fine.
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# Sample data
data = {
    'Date': ['2024-08-01', '2024-08-02', '2024-08-05'],
    'A': [48.06, 49.06, 50.06],
    'B': [30.9, 31.9, 32.9]
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert 'Date' to datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Plot with Seaborn
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plot = sns.lineplot(x='Date', y='A', data=df, label='A')
sns.lineplot(x='Date', y='B', data=df, label='B')

# Format the x-axis to show dates correctly
format_ymd = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
plot.xaxis.set_major_formatter(format_ymd)

# Rotate x-axis labels for better readability
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

plt.legend()
plt.show()

